# Since upgrade to wily, x11vnc will no longer start

Tags: vnc

Since I upgraded to wily this morning, my x11vnc server will no longer start. The usual command:

```
sudo x11vnc -nomodtweak -forever -display :0 -auth guess
```

results in:

```
27/10/2015 21:56:57 x11vnc version: 0.9.13 lastmod: 2011-08-10  pid: 5424
27/10/2015 21:56:57 -auth guess: failed for display=':0'
27/10/2015 21:56:57 -auth guess: since we are root, retrying with FD_XDM=1
27/10/2015 21:56:57 -auth guess: failed for display=':0'
```

I use this to connect from home to my desktop at work over VPN. At this point, I am logged in to the desktop at work and I have a display running, so it's not a headless system nor is it stuck with a gdm greeter.

I am running the gnome3 flavor of Ubuntu with lowlatency kernel and gdm, no unity and no ibus.

Any idea what may have caused this?

Peter

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the default display changed from :0 to :1.

Also, it no longer seems to work when run as super user.

Use `-display :1` and get rid of the `sudo` to make it work.